# Transforming Badly Formatted Data into something useful

Tags: python, json

Just for fun, someone just dropped a json file needing to be transformed into a Time Series on to my lap. Unfortunately for me, it looks like this:

```
  "messages": [
{
  "format": "string",
  "topic": "camera1",
  "timestamp": 1669253760775,
  "payload": "{\"AnalyticalOutput\":[\"1\",\"6\",\"6\",\"9\",\"2\",\"5\",\"3\",\"7\",\"6\",\"0\",\".\",\"6\",\"7\",\"6\",\"4\",\"8\",\"8\",\"9\"],\"Timestamp\":\"1669253759.7708852\"}",
  "qos": 0
},
```

What I need to do is to transform thousands of lines of *that* into something manageable for python to use.
For that frame right there, what I need, exactly, to extract from it is the information from the Payload, specifically the numbers 1669253760.64889 and 1669253759.7708852, as columns of something like a csv, or anything that pandas could read.

Where do I even start with something like this?

Comment: The payload looks like JSON encoded as string. So just decode it in Python to a dict and extract values from it. The list of digit strings can be "join"ed to a single string and converted to a" float".

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example of drilling down into the `payload`

```
import json
d = {  "messages": [
{
  "format": "string",
  "topic": "camera1",
  "timestamp": 1669253760775,
  "payload": "{\"AnalyticalOutput\":[\"1\",\"6\",\"6\",\"9\",\"2\",\"5\",\"3\",\"7\",\"6\",\"0\",\".\",\"6\",\"7\",\"6\",\"4\",\"8\",\"8\",\"9\"],\"Timestamp\":\"1669253759.7708852\"}",
  "qos": 0
},
]}
payload = json.loads(d['messages'][0]['payload'])

for k,v in payload.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        v = float(''.join(v))
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: I realized this is very similar to @Michael Butscher's comment as well.

Comment: And for this, you just import a json, and then it through something similar?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what does the [0] mean in that snippet. I not familiar with jsons in python?

Comment: Hi @Johney, `[0]` gets the first item in the list.  You're list may be longer so it may be easier just to iterate through it and process the payload for each.